# query from athena a file in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am complete newbie on this. I have this file in amazon s3.

How can I query this .tar.gz  from Athena?

[image]

I am assuming I have to somehow decompress and ‘restore’ to ‘athena’? But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I would recommend to use AWS Glue to crawl the data for you. Glue will automatically infer a database schema for you, that works with Athena. I have not tried if AWS Glue can crawl tar-balls. Some docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html . If you are not satisfied with the table layout generated by AWS Glue, you can export the schema  using ```describe table```, change the column definitions, and then use ```create table``` to create your adapted version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly query files in AWS Athena that are in .gz format as well as any flat files. If your tar file contains multiple .gz files and they are of the same file format then you don't need to gunzip them to .tsv.

Since, you have already converted to .tsv files make sure the files of the same format are put into a folder e.g. 
s3://bucketname/folder/file1.gz
s3://bucketname/folder/file2.gz

etc. file1 and file2 should have the same structure.

Then define your AWS Athena table on top of this. Sample script below -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name (
yr INT,
 quarter INT,
 month INT,
 dayofmonth INT,
 dayofweek INT,
 flightdate STRING
)
 PARTITIONED BY (year STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 LOCATION 's3://bucketname/folder/';
```

Keeping homogeneous files is not mandatory but recommended so that you can add remove files under the same folder and just update the partition information every time there is a change.

Run MSCK REPAIR TABLE to refresh partition metadata each time a new partition is added to this table.

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name ;
```

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html#tsv-example

Comment: thanks! I did everything, and when I query the table, I get 0 records. What could I be doing wrong?

My wild guess is this part: 

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 

Is it really that? How can I know?

Comment: Are all the TSVs files of the same format / layout? Also, is the bucket encrypted? What did the msck  table repair yield. Unless you don't provide all the details we won't be able to provide inputs...   can you share a sample file 
..

Comment: Thanks! It is only 1 tsv file. Bucket is not encrypted. MSCK was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query tarballs. Athena requires gzipped or uncompressed text-files. Other options are ORC or parquet files. You will need to untar the file and create a gzip file with just the .txt in it.

Comment: thanks, I uncompressed them and uploaded them, they are several .tsv files. How can I query them from athena?